# OS X Uptime History

Tags: objective-c, macos, uptime

How to find os x uptime history?
There is "last reboot" command on termina which reports last reboot history. How do I write a program with objective C that gets all uptime history ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: I need to know how can i retrieve the times in which system has been turned on and figure out how to write a code which acts like last reboot command.

Comment: But there would be some guest, some normal, some admin account? each one having differnt files...

Comment: I need it for all account types .But if you can provide a method for admin at least, I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `last` command is part of Darwin and is [open-source](http://www.opensource.apple.com). [Here's the code.](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-149/last/last.c)